# Empty OpenFileDialoge when open image

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

I have designed a vb.net application which uses OpenFileDialoge to open a picture in PictureBox.
My machine is windows 7 32bit and this is my code:

```
    Dim directoryName As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
    Try
        Dim dialog As New OpenFileDialog
        directoryName = ""
        dialog.InitialDirectory = directoryName
        dialog.Filter = "Pictures|*.jpg|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        dialog.FilterIndex = 1
        dialog.RestoreDirectory = True
        If dialog.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            TextBox8.Text = dialog.FileName
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(TextBox8.Text)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
```

everything is good on my machine, but on the client machine who has windows 7 64bit, when he trying to open an image, he got like this Picture:

[image]

Also, I tried to change the .Net framwork with different versions but nothing happened, anyone have an idea please?

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved my problem after 5 days of searching and trying time and time again.
I was using MS Acess 2010 database with my program as back end and the solution was to convert it to MS Acess 2003.
I don't know what the relate of that!, but it's solved.